# Is there an easier way to see the contents of the optional Windows 7 updates?

Tags: windows-update

Here's my problem: Windows 7 tells me it has updates, both important and optional. I always accept all the important updates, but I don't want to accept every optional update. So, I'd like to quickly see what's in each optional update.

However, the only way I know to see the contents of the optional updates is click the "More information" link in the right panel of the select updates window. This is clunky, because it opens a new web page for each update. I wish it would give the title or a brief summary right there in the window, so I could quickly go through the list and see which updates are potentially interesting. There's plenty of space in that panel, but it just fills it up with boilerplate text: "Install this update to resolve issues in Windows..."

Is there something I'm missing? Is there a better way quickly see descriptive titles or summaries of the optional updates in the "Select the updates you wish to install" window?

Comment: I know of no way to add details to the updater window, would be nice.

Comment: On the left side of the Windows Update window, there should be tabs for important and optional updates. Or are you already looking at that, and you want more information?

Comment: You should only get `Optional Updates` for devices currently installed in your system.  Why are you getting updates for devices that have never been installed in your system.

Comment: @Ramhound: I've been prompted for Optional Updates for Silverlight (multiple times), Bing Desktop and the like. They are not meant for hardware only, although I guess it depends on whether the *Microsoft Update* option is checked under WU settings.